# buildozer build not progressing when building a simple kivy app

Tags: python, macos, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an extremely basic kivy hello world program using buildozer for Android, and it's been stuck for an hour.

This is the program code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("2.1.0")

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App


class HelloWorldApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HelloWorldApp().run()
```

After creating the spec file with `buildozer init`, I edited the title, package.name and package.domain

I then run the command

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

It then runs for bit, before getting stuck. I've left the terminal open for an hour and it hasn't progressed at all

This is the entire terminal output after I pressed ctrl c and ran `buildozer -v android debug` again

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
/bin/sh: dpkg: command not found
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.39.0/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /Users/leonlee/Library/Python/3.10/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /Users/leonlee/Documents/Programming/Python/Kivy/hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /Users/leonlee/Documents/Programming/Python/Kivy/hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master cc6481b0 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2718 from kivy/release-2022.12.20
# Run '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'toml\' \'packaging\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /Users/leonlee/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /Users/leonlee/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 25b
# Android NDK found at /Users/leonlee/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Run '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain aab -h --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/leonlee/Documents/Programming/Python/Kivy/hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug'
# Cwd /Users/leonlee/Documents/Programming/Python/Kivy/hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
```

The first time I run `buildozer -v android debug`, it had some different lines, but ends up getting stuck at the same place.

I've tried removing the spec file and the .buildozer folder and rerunning `buildozer init`, but it does the same thing.

I've also tried adding kivy==2.1.0 in the application requirements line of the spec.

Both of these things don't fix the issue.

I've also tried searching for other posts with this issue, but haven't been able to find one with my issue. All the posts I've found actually give an error message, while my terminal just does nothing

My laptop is a Macbook Pro with an M1 Pro running the latest version of macOS Ventura, and I'm using Python 3.10.0. I'm also using openjdk 1.8.0_292